# Remove and Replace all html content in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, substring

I want a query in SQL Server to update the data by removing all its html content.

Please see sample data below.

This is a sample text.

```
<html><head></head><body><p>This is a sample text.</p></body></html>
```

I only need to retain the plain text and remove all these html contents including the tags. I think, the reference could be from `<html*` to `*/html >`

Any suggestions please?

Comment: use replace  function , you can replace the <,</,> with white space  via this function

Answer (score 0):

`Charindex` + `While Loop`. Try this.

```
DECLARE @html  VARCHAR(5000)='This is a sample text < html >< head ></head >< body >< p >This is a sample text.< p >< /body >< /html >',
        @start INT,
        @end   INT

WHILE Charindex('<', @html) > 0
  BEGIN
      SET @start= Charindex('<', @html)
      SET @end = Charindex('>', @html)

      SELECT @html = Stuff(@html, @start, ( @end - @start ) + 1, '')
  END

SELECT @html --This is a sample text This is a sample text.
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, will this apply to all rows having html?

Each record has plain text version as well as html version of it.

Comment: This will remove all the words between < and >